# How do I dynamically create column in a SQL view using a Select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I currently have this statement in my SQL View (SQL Server 2008 R2) which works great for taking these two tables and displaying them in a single SQL View.

```
SELECT     sym1, msg1 
FROM       table_src1
UNION ALL
SELECT     sym2, msg2
FROM       table_src2
```

Expanding on this, I'm looking for a way to dynamically create/generate a column in this View. Let's call the column 'src'. This column should be a varchar data type and set to 'src1' or 'src2' based on the above select statement per row.

Example data the View would return would look like this:

```
sym        msg         src
symbolA    morning     src1
symbolB    night       src2
```

Can this be accomplished within my View? I've read similar questions where the answer is typically a stored procedure but nothing is saying it can't be done in a View.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [automatically create views for a bunch of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237740/automatically-create-views-for-a-bunch-of-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT     sym1, msg1, 'src1' as src 
FROM       table_src1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT     sym2, msg2, 'src2' as src 
FROM       table_src2
```