# T-SQL : Script to create view with columns from a select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I have some bulk views to create for an entire database.

To create a view the general syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [TABLE_NAME] 
AS 
    SELECT [COLUMN1], [COLUMN2], [COLUMN3], [COLUMN4]
    FROM [TABLE_NAME]
    WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

I would like to set the column names in the script above by querying the column names (`[COLULMN1]`, `[COLUMN2]`, etc) from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Is there a way to achieve this by table name?

Comment: yes, you need dynamic SQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [automatically create views for a bunch of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237740/automatically-create-views-for-a-bunch-of-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is your friend good programmer. What you want to do is get a csv list of COLUMNS. Then using dynamic sql you can auto generate the rest of the code.

```
 declare @columns AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COLUMNS = NULL


select  @COLUMNS = coalesce(@columns+',','')+c.name from syscolumns as c
inner join sysobjects as o on c.id = o.id
WHERE O.NAME = 'change me to your table name'

SELECT @COLUMNS
SELECT ' CREATE VIEW ' + 'COOL VIEW NAME' + ' AS ' +
' SELECT ' + @COLUMNS +
 ' FROM '+ ' change me to your table name '+
 ' WITH CHECK OPTION;'
```

***EDIT***

I purposely didn't declare the view anywhere. If you want to declare the view just execute the scripts like so. ***BUT YOU SHOULD NEVER just execute code on your servers without reading it all*** I purposely excluded the execution part as I think it is bad judgement just to cut and paste code and execute it without understanding/testing.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)


    SELECT @sql = ' CREATE VIEW ' + 'COOL VIEW NAME' + ' AS ' +
    ' SELECT ' + @COLUMNS +
     ' FROM '+ ' change me to your table name '+
     ' WITH CHECK OPTION;' 

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: Wonderful and SMART IDEA!  Thank you very much for your suggestion.  I'll give it a try and let you know how it works!

Comment: Tried this and it didn't seem to work.  The following was executed successfully but I don't see the view  being created anywhere...  ??

Comment: `DECLARE @fieldnames VARCHAR(MAX)
select @fieldnames = coalesce (@fieldnames+', ', '') + V_FIELDNAME
from tmp_fieldNames


--Select @fieldnames

Select 'CREATE VIEW ' + 'DS_STAGE_QAS.dbo.DYN_MARC_P2004' + ' AS ' + 
 'SELECT ' + @fieldnames + 
   'FROM ' + 'STAGE_MARC' +
   'WHERE STAGE_MARC.PLANT = 2040' + 
   'with check option;'`

Comment: Disregard - it will work..  I just have some clean up to do.  Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option... replace "MyTableName" with the table name you want, or wrap it in a cursor that reads TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS into @tableName:

```
DECLARE @tableName sysname;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @columnList nvarchar(max);
SELECT @tableName = 'MyTableName';
SELECT @columnList = '';
SELECT @columnList += CASE WHEN LEN(@columnList) = 0 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
SELECT @sql = 'CREATE VIEW [TABLE_NAME] AS 
 SELECT ' + @columnList + '
FROM [' + @tableName + ']
 WITH CHECK OPTION;'

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql);
```