# Creating a View from Table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, view

i am trying to create a view from a SQL table
following is a (very simplified...) subset of data in the table:

[image]

in the view i have to show only the EC_MODEL that have Installation as last EC_TYPE
that is, from the table, only the sensor from Station1 should be selected; on the contrary, the EC_MODEL from Station2 must not be selected, because the last operation is a Removal.
Well, I couldn't write the query that does the operation...how could I solve ?
thanks

Comment: How do you know which operation is last?

Comment: You will need a field to order by, so you can determine 'last'.  If not you will need to build a case statement or some such to set an order based on ec_type.  Once you can do an order look into row_number() and / or rank() to select the 'last' records where ec_type = Installation

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: @uzi, you are right; i missed a column (OPERATION_DATE) which I use for the ordering criterium. so you should imagine that all those records are ordered by _DATE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14241084/109941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select
    ec_model
from (
    select
        ec_model, ec_type, rn = row_number() over (partition by ec_model order by operation_date desc)
    from
        myTable
) t
where
    rn = 1
    and ec_type = 'installation'
```